# How to increase the line spacing in a multiline textbox in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

```
<asp:TextBox ID="questionTb" runat="server" Height="160px" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" MaxLength="2"  Width="100%" OnTextChanged="questionTb_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

The above given code segment provides an output which is mentioned below.

[image]

Is there any way to increase the space between two lines? (Ex: line-spacing: 1.5 )

Comment: @holydragon I have referred that already. It did't solve my problem

Comment: I don't think a normal textbox can give you linespacing. You would need some kind of richtext box for that.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel in asp.net there is no RichTextBox. It is available only on windows forms applications. Do u know any other way to fix this?

Comment: try css `textarea { line-height: 200% !important; }`

Comment: @VDWWD Thats great. it worked. Thanks alot !

Comment: You're welcome. You can try it also without the `!important`. I've added it because I think something is overriding the defaults since the text should not be overlapping in the first place.

Comment: yes your prediction was correct. now it works well.

Comment: That's why I added _some kind of_ ;) If the `line-height` already solves it, that's good. Better than having to pull in some 3rd party library control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct answer for my problem is:

```
textarea { line-height: 200% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    textarea { 
                padding: 10px;
                line-height: 1.3;
            }
```